# Renaming file when download, but not working for AWS S3

Tags: javascript, php, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this code that rename a file name when downloading but is not working for files from AWS S3

code:

```
 <a href="https://gzfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/1450501725_test1.mp3" download="file.mp3">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

It works when the href is from another server but not from AWS S3.

Comment: from which browser are you trying to download from s3, coz [download](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute of `a` is not supported in IE or safari.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Content-Disposition` header from server side. It will work with all browsers. `download` attribute is not supported in some browsers like IE.

```
 <?php
     http_send_content_disposition("file.mp3", true);
     http_send_content_type("audio/mpeg");
     http_throttle(0.1, 2048);
     http_send_file("path/1450501725_test1.mp3");
 ?>
```